# Help installing Chrome OS

Tags: helpfile

I lost my windows 7 recovery disks and product key so I was stupid to install Ubuntu because I'm not tech savvy. I barely learned Sudo install apt-get and I can't get Microsoft word on Ubuntu for college work and I would like to have Chrome OS installed. So here are my questions

1.) Where can I get a copy of the ISO for Chrome OS to download and install on USB Drive? Link to a download will be great.

2.) I thought I downloaded a ISO called Chromium but when I restarted and presses F10 for boot options my USB is not showing it just says Ubuntu and a couple things about Ubuntu test.

3.) Terminal commands I may need so I can extract and install Chrome so I can just boot into Chrome.

What I want is Chrome OS I can boot to. I am very simple so if you do have the time to help if you can just simply describe easy step by step instructions on where I can find chrome OS, how to get the file onto USB so it can be bootable and how to be able to get chrome OS booted

Comment: **This is not about Ubuntu.** Questions about other Linux distributions can be asked on Unix & Linux, those about Windows on Super User, those about Apple products on Ask Different and generic programming questions on Stack Overflow, blah, blah. **Having said that, Chrome OS is on topic on [unix.se]** but not really here. Perhaps this question will be migrated there in the future.

Comment: ^ What cat said. But also, why not just reinstall Windows 7? You can get the ISO online if you have a valid product key.

Answer (score 1):

1: Figure out of your computer is Legacy or UEFI. In the BIOS boot options, if there is no [UEFI] tag next to your harddrive/USB, then you are Legacy. If there is, and/or your PC shipped with >Windows 8, then you are UEFI.

2: Download the latest ChromeOS image here:

https://chromium.arnoldthebat.co.uk/index.php?dir=daily%2F

Be sure to select the correct image for your hardware (amd64=64-bit, x86=32-bit).

3: Extract the image with 7zip:

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
```

and extract it from terminal

```
7z x chromiumimage.image.7z
```

4: Burn the image to a USB, preferably with Unetbootin.

5: Boot the USB.

6: When booted, press `Ctrl+Alt+F2`. Login as `chronos`. The password, I believe, for Arnold's builds, is `password`.

7: Then, you can install ChromeOS to your hard disk with the command

```
/usr/sbin/chromeos-install
```

Comment: Ok so I downloaded a iso from link above. I sudo apt-get p7zip then i typed the 7z x line and got error there is no such archive. What went wrong?

Comment: @JimmyALondo Did you navigate to your downloads folder? (cd ~/Downloads)